# How to set default page in WCF when its start with windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-services

i have a WCF service with windows service. When i install the service, i access the web service but the page "Default.aspx" insn't show.

I configure the web.config with this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <!-- this line enables default documents for a directory -->
        <files>
            <clear />
            <!-- removes the existing default document list -->
            <add value="Default.aspx"></add>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

but not work.

I try in  "Properties -> Web -> click Specific Page" but not working too.

How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to serve ASPX pages which is different from handling WCF requests.

Check out this thread for similar discussion:

[Can a self-hosted WCF app host ASP.NET pages/handle POST without IIS?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ccb72101-d21d-432a-92a5-30f2c3bf96b2/can-a-selfhosted-wcf-app-host-aspnet-pageshandle-post-without-iis?forum=wcf)